# Selenium profile import -chrome

Tags: python, selenium, chromium

Afternoon everyone,

Hopefully an easy question to answer but something I cannot work out.

I'm trying to import my user profile into Selenium to automate tasks so things like logins will be kept. Problem is despite trying the profile does not import and no error is thrown.

My only changes to my code have been to use 'service' instead of execute_file to prevent depreciate warnings.

I've also tried copying the Default profile and renaming in a different location but the dame error occurs. I've also try another Google profile of mine to no avail.

Some documentation I read says I need to add a second arguement for 'op' to enable to profile but this isn't allowed and fails if I do.

My code:

***ser = Service(r'C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\Selenium automation\test\chromedriver.exe')

op = Options()

op = op.add_argument(r"user-data-dir=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default")

browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=ser, options=op)

browser.get("https://stackoverflow.com")***